# CSS issues: Ddisplay the horizontal line below Out of stock

Tags: css

Please visit this link :

http://demoexample.com/x9460-disney-planes.html?___SID=U

here you can see  "out of stock" is separated by "Availability" through horizontal line.

but here it is fine

http://demoexample.com/cbn10-disney-planes-avalanche.html

I want to display the Out of stock above that line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `height` assigned to the `Quick_2` class. The reason why the 2nd link looks better is b/c the left column has 2 buttons, which makes the height of the left side bigger. Therefore, the right column's height is expanded.

For your 2nd question coming up, why is the "7 days Replacement Garuantee ?" below the line - you need to clear your floats on the container element that houses the float elements. You want to add this class, `clearfix`, on the `Quick` class' element.

Take a look at [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

[image]